# Set logger level for individual appenders with log4js-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, log4js-node

I am using [log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node) on Node.js

Is there a way to configure log level of each logger & appender pair ?

For example:

I have the default `console` appender and a `dateFile` appender. I want `dateFile` appender to capture all messages according to globally configured category levels.

Now I'd like `console` appender to completely ignore messages of certain log categories because I need just a high level view on console. Printing all the log messages on console is just too much noise to follow.

Is that even possible? I could not find any relevant API for that. I could only set levels for individual loggers using for example `myLogger.setLevel("ERROR")`, but that affects all the appenders.